# Styling react-toolbox elements with className

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I seem to be having some issues in regards to styling the components without using a theme.  I just want to change a couple of colors without needing to create a new theme per element.

In this case, I just want to change the color of the bar to a brownish color and right now I have an input class as follows:

```
import style from './style.scss'
const TextInput = (props) => {
    <Input className={style.textInput} {...props} />
}
```

And in my style.scss file:

```
.textInput {
   .bar {
     background-color: #663300;
   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

ClassName doesn't work like that.
You can't pass a Css style to a className, that is wrong.

Either pass the class names you want to apply as a string (in your case I guess it would be className="textInput bar") or you can create a className with [classNames library](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) (in any case the final result will be a string).

Just make sure you're styles are included in the page that the component is going to render and **react will be smart enough to render the correct css class for each component**.

As you can check [in here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html#nodes-and-elements) ClassName is a `string`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I modeled mine after this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030308/styling-with-react-toolboxs-button-not-working

Comment: You can see in the source code https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/blob/dev/lib/button/Button.js#L95 (little bit messy) that the className is a string, not a css style, set a breakpoint in there and see the result from that line. That answer doesn't look good to me..

Comment: OP is using CSS modules and I think this answerer doesn't realize that